# Edit component inside Drawer component

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-admin

I am using `react-admin` framework and I am trying to put the `<Edit>` component inside `<Drawer>` component. I need this in order to be able to save changes done in my `JsonInput`.

This is my custom component:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { fetchUtils, CardActions, EditButton, Button, List, Datagrid, Edit } from 'react-admin';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import JsonInput from 'react-json-view';

import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import IconKeyboardArrowRight from '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowRight';
import { SimpleForm } from 'ra-ui-materialui/lib/form';

const divStyle = {
 width: '400px',
 margin: '1em'
};

export default class JsonEditButton extends React.Component {
 constructor(props, context) {
  super(props, context);
  this.state = { showPanel: false };
 }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ showPanel: true });
  };

  handleCloseClick = () => {
    this.setState({ showPanel: false });
  };

  onChange = (value) => {
    const { updated_src, name, namespace, new_value, existing_value } = value;
    //this.onChange(updated_src);
  }

 render() {
  const { showPanel } = this.state;


  return (
    <div>
      <Button label="Upravit JSON" onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <EditIcon />
      </Button>

      <Fragment>
        <Drawer
          anchor="right"
          open={showPanel}
          onClose={this.handleCloseClick}
        >
          <div>
            <Button label="Zavřít" onClick={this.handleCloseClick}>
              <IconKeyboardArrowRight />
            </Button>
          </div>
          <div style={divStyle}>
            {props => (
              <Edit {...props}>
                <SimpleForm>
                  {this.props.record && <JsonInput src={this.props.record} name={null} displayDataTypes={false} displayObjectSize={false} onEdit={this.onChange} onAdd={this.onChange} onDelete={this.onChange} />}
                </SimpleForm>
              </Edit>
            )}
          </div>
        </Drawer>
      </Fragment>
    </div>
  );
 }
};
```

However this doesnt return any `HTML`.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code of the whole component?

Comment: @AtinSingh do you mean my whole custom component?

Comment: Yes. Your whole custom component.

Comment: Thanks.. have you checked the console for any errors?

Comment: It only returns this warning:

`Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this may help

```
<div style={divStyle}>

              <Edit {...this.props}>
                <SimpleForm>
                  {this.props.record && <JsonInput src={this.props.record} name={null} displayDataTypes={false} displayObjectSize={false} onEdit={this.onChange} onAdd={this.onChange} onDelete={this.onChange} />}
                </SimpleForm>
              </Edit>

 </div>
```

the previous code where `{props => ()}` is actually a function or you could try this

```
<div style={divStyle}>
            {props => (
              return(
              <Edit {...props}>
                <SimpleForm>
                  {this.props.record && <JsonInput src={this.props.record} name={null} displayDataTypes={false} displayObjectSize={false} onEdit={this.onChange} onAdd={this.onChange} onDelete={this.onChange} />}
                </SimpleForm>
              </Edit>)
            )}
          </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, any of those solution does not seem to work. The first cant load the data from this.props, and the second one expects expression after return().

Thank you for ideas though.

Comment: where does the `props` in `{props => ()}` comes from?

Comment: Honestly I dont really know thinking about it. But `this.props.` comes from a List where I implement this component.

Comment: Do you want to pass that data from `this.props` to `<Edit >` component ? Or something inside this.props to it?

Comment: Well yes, I want to edit the changes that were made in JsonInput, If I put the JsonInpit to the Drawer by itself, it will show the data that I want without a problem, but I need to be able to save the changes after editing whats inside the input.

Comment: I tried to put the input inside `SimpleForm` tag, which creates a save button, but the button isnt doing anything after clicking on it.